# Is there a pandas function to delete rows by comparing two values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have a DataFrame which has a column with increasing numbers, representing the seconds of a day like this:

| Index | SecOfDay |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 21 |
| 4 | 23 |
| 5 | 31 |

Now I want to delete every row of the DataFrame, where the difference of secOfDay to the column before is smaller than 10. To have the DataFrame look like this:

| Index | SecOfDay |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 21 |
| 4 | 31 |

The only way to solve this was for me was a loop. Is there a way to do this more elegant in pandas maybe?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Should not row `5` in the first dataframe be removed, since `31-23 < 10` ?

Comment: If firstly row 4 is removed since 23-21 < 10, then the next step should be 31-21 = 10.
But the below answer works perectly! :) Still thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0, 10, 21, 23, 26, 31, 43, 48, 61], columns=['sec'])
```

`df`

```
    sec
0   0
1   10
2   21
3   23
4   26
5   31
6   43
7   48
8   61
```

**Code**

```
result = [df['sec'].iloc[0]]
for i in df['sec']:
    if i - result[-1] >= 10:
        result.append(i)
```

`result` :

```
[0, 10, 21, 31, 43, 61]
```

make `result` to dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['sec'])
```

**output**

```
    sec
0   0
1   10
2   21
3   31
4   43
5   61
```

I could have made it without loop, but it was much messier.
I will appreciate any other opinions